# Children could not be evaluated

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to make the following query work:

```
var query = from c in context.ChargeMultipliers where c.Description.Replace(" ", string.Empty).ToUpper() == description.ToUpper().Replace(" ", string.Empty)select c;
```

In the above I am trying to trim the sql field "Description" into a string with no spaces, all uppercase and a comparison description string also trimmed and converted to upper. However, I receive "Children could not be evaluated"as the result of the query.

Any ideas on why this happens?

Comment: Please post the exception stack trace.

Comment: Probably Linq to Entities could not translate c.Description.Replace(" ", string.Empty).ToUpper() in valid SQL, you simply try to use Linq to objects on Linq to Entities.

Answer (score 0):

When debugging your query, following SQL statement is generated:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
    FROM [dbo].[ChargeMultipliers] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE (UPPER(REPLACE([Extent1].[Description], N' ', @p__linq__0))) = (UPPER(REPLACE(@p__linq__1, N' ', @p__linq__2)))
```

As you can see, the comparison is also trimmed in the SQL statement and string.Empty woud be passed as a parameter which is maybe not the empty character in the understanding of the database.

I would prefer to do this before building the query:

```
        string descriptionTrim = description.Replace(" ", string.Empty).ToUpper();

        var query = from c in context.ChargeMultipliers
                    where c.Description.Replace(" ", "").ToUpper() == descriptionTrim
                    select c;
```

The generated SQL query looks quite simpler now and you can easily find out what really will be compared in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
    FROM [dbo].[ChargeMultipliers] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE (UPPER(REPLACE([Extent1].[Description], N' ', N''))) = @p__linq__0
```

Comment: That's true. Also replacing `string.Empty` with `""` will eliminate one of the parameters. But all that doesn't answer the OP question.

Comment: I just improved my answer. Replacing string.Empty with "" might help because the c# string.Empty must not necessarily match with the database's 'empty'.

Comment: The point is that improved or not, you are answering a different question, not the one asked by the OP, which is what is causing *“Children could not be evaluated” exception*.

Comment: You're right. I was more attracted by the query than the error message, which I've never seen outside the debugging mode by the way.